# apache rewrite rule, looking in other folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

ok so I have this rewrite rule on my httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/dev/html5>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ snapshots/playlist-%2\.html [NC,L,PT]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla(.*)MSIE\ 9.0(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/dev/html5/#!/$1 [R,NC,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [NC,L,PT]
```

what I'm interested in is, when I have _escaped_fragment in the query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)/(.*)$
```

I want to look for the folder snapshots, but the folder is not inside html5 folder is one level up, so how can I look for that folder?? like this

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ../snapshots/playlist-%2\.html [NC,L,PT]
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to allow that folder permission by adding it in your vhost config

In other words you'll need to configure apache to allow the folder, so just like `<directory icons>` and `<directory error docs>` are setup by default. Maybe make it an alias:

```
Alias /snapshots/ "/var/www/html/dev/snapshots/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/dev/snapshots/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then once it is aliased it will be available at example.com/snapshots/ so

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /snapshots/playlist-%2\.html [NC,L,PT]
```